# Prove if $\#S > \frac{1}{2}\#G$ that $\langle S \rangle = G$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a finite group, and $S \subset G$ is a subset with $\#S > \frac{1}{2}\#G$. Prove that
$$
\langle S \rangle = G
$$
and
that every $x \in G$ can be written as $x = s_1 \cdot s_2$ with $s_1, s_2 \in S$.

I believe I can use that:
Given $x \in G$, we must prove that  $S$ and $\{xs^{-1} \mid s \in S\}$ can't be disjunct. But I need help

Comment: This is a FAQ, with many duplicates on this site. Please search next time before posting.

Comment: i dont have the answer yet

Comment: The duplicates show that $G=S\cdot S$, so that $G=\langle S\rangle$. As you wrote yourself: "and
that every $x \in G$ can be written as $x = s_1 \cdot s_2$ with $s_1, s_2 \in S$."

Comment: Oh im sorry i didnt know,, $G = S \cdot S = \langle S \rangle$?

Comment: Yes, $G$ is generated by  $S\cdot S=\{s_1s_2\mid s_i\in S\}$. So $G$ can be generated by all elements $s_1,s_2$ in $S$.